# Is it correct to use "squad with me" if i want to ask my friends to be part of my squad?

Tags: meaning, grammar

**English is not my native language so sorry for any possible funny mistakes**

I am trying to choose a domain for my website. The domain ends with **.me**.

My website is about building squads for games.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Within the context it would work as a phrase or domain name.

Comment: Naming exercises, which may involve English so far from standard that hardly any rules apply, are off-topic.

Comment: It's informal, but pretty good in the right context.